# Error Connecting virtual machine to oracle, using python (error DPY-4011)

Tags: python, oracle, virtual-machine, python-oracledb

I'm using the oracledb library to connect my python application to an oracle database. I can connect normally using python on my computer, but I have a virtual machine, running Ubuntu, which is using the same network as the computer, that cannot connect. here is the output when I try:

Python: 3.8.10 
Oracle: SE19 
Conn. string: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=NAME)(SERVER=dedicated)))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/arthur/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 995, in wrapped
    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arthur/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 124, in __init__
    impl.connect(params_impl)
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 309, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 169, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 188, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._connect
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 255, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 233, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 301, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._receive_packet
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/buffer.pyx", line 1080, in oracledb.thin_impl.ReadBuffer.receive_packet
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/buffer.pyx", line 426, in oracledb.thin_impl.ReadBuffer._receive_packet_helper
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/buffer.pyx", line 293, in oracledb.thin_impl.ReadBuffer._get_data_from_socket
  File "/home/arthur/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oracledb/errors.py", line 103, in _raise_err
    raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
```

Searching this error, I found that it might be a firewall problem, but it's deactivated in the V.M.

What else could I try?

EDIT: After setting the ENV variable here is the output(I hid some sensitive data)

```
2022-08-04 16:40:44.246 [socket: 3] Sending packet:
0000 : 01 10 00 00 01 00 00 00 |........|
0008 : 01 3E 01 2C 0C 01 20 00 |.>.,....|
0016 : FF FF 4F 98 00 00 00 01 |..O.....|
0024 : 00 C6 00 4A 00 00 00 00 |...J....|
0032 : 80 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0040 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0048 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0056 : 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 |........|
0064 : FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0072 : 00 01 28 44 45 53 43 52 |..(DESCR|
0080 : 49 50 54 49 4F 4E 3D 28 |IPTION=(|
0088 : 41 44 44 52 45 53 53 3D |ADDRESS=|
0096 : 28 50 52 4F 54 4F 43 4F |(PROTOCO|
0104 : 4C 3D 54 43 50 29 28 48 |L=TCP)(H|
0112 : 4F 53 54 3D 31 37 32 2E |OST=IPP.|
0120 : 32 30 2E 33 2E 32 35 34 |IP.I.IPP|
0128 : 29 28 50 4F 52 54 3D 31 |)(PORT=1|
0136 : 35 32 31 29 29 28 43 4F |521))(CO|
0144 : 4E 4E 45 43 54 5F 44 41 |NNECT_DA|
0152 : 54 41 3D 28 53 45 52 56 |TA=(SERV|
0160 : 49 43 45 5F 4E 41 4D 45 |ICE_NAME|
0168 : 3D 46 4F 52 54 45 53 45 |=SERVICE|
0176 : 43 29 28 53 45 52 56 45 |C)(SERVE|
0184 : 52 3D 64 65 64 69 63 61 |R=dedica|
0192 : 74 65 64 29 28 43 49 44 |ted)(CID|
0200 : 3D 28 50 52 4F 47 52 41 |=(PROGRA|
0208 : 4D 3D 2F 75 73 72 2F 62 |M=/usr/b|
0216 : 69 6E 2F 70 79 74 68 6F |in/pytho|
0224 : 6E 33 29 28 48 4F 53 54 |n3)(HOST|
0232 : 3D 61 72 74 68 75 72 2D |=arthur-|
0240 : 56 69 72 74 75 61 6C 2D |Virtual-|
0248 : 4D 61 63 68 69 6E 65 29 |Machine)|
0256 : 28 55 53 45 52 3D 61 72 |(USER=ar|
0264 : 74 68 75 72 29 29 29 29 |thur))))|

2022-08-04 16:40:44.391 [socket: 3] Receiving packet:
0000 : 00 08 00 00 0B 00 00 00 |........|

2022-08-04 16:40:44.391 [socket: 3] Sending packet:
0000 : 01 10 00 00 01 00 00 00 |........|
0008 : 01 3E 01 2C 0C 01 20 00 |.>.,....|
0016 : FF FF 4F 98 00 00 00 01 |..O.....|
0024 : 00 C6 00 4A 00 00 00 00 |...J....|
0032 : 80 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0040 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0048 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0056 : 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 |........|
0064 : FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0072 : 00 01 28 44 45 53 43 52 |..(DESCR|
0080 : 49 50 54 49 4F 4E 3D 28 |IPTION=(|
0088 : 41 44 44 52 45 53 53 3D |ADDRESS=|
0096 : 28 50 52 4F 54 4F 43 4F |(PROTOCO|
0104 : 4C 3D 54 43 50 29 28 48 |L=TCP)(H|
0112 : 4F 53 54 3D 31 37 32 2E |OST=IPP.|
0120 : 32 30 2E 33 2E 32 35 34 |IP.I.IPP|
0128 : 29 28 50 4F 52 54 3D 31 |)(PORT=1|
0136 : 35 32 31 29 29 28 43 4F |521))(CO|
0144 : 4E 4E 45 43 54 5F 44 41 |NNECT_DA|
0152 : 54 41 3D 28 53 45 52 56 |TA=(SERV|
0160 : 49 43 45 5F 4E 41 4D 45 |ICE_NAME|
0168 : 3D 46 4F 52 54 45 53 45 |=SERVICE|
0176 : 43 29 28 53 45 52 56 45 |C)(SERVE|
0184 : 52 3D 64 65 64 69 63 61 |R=dedica|
0192 : 74 65 64 29 28 43 49 44 |ted)(CID|
0200 : 3D 28 50 52 4F 47 52 41 |=(PROGRA|
0208 : 4D 3D 2F 75 73 72 2F 62 |M=/usr/b|
0216 : 69 6E 2F 70 79 74 68 6F |in/pytho|
0224 : 6E 33 29 28 48 4F 53 54 |n3)(HOST|
0232 : 3D 61 72 74 68 75 72 2D |=arthur-|
0240 : 56 69 72 74 75 61 6C 2D |Virtual-|
0248 : 4D 61 63 68 69 6E 65 29 |Machine)|
0256 : 28 55 53 45 52 3D 61 72 |(USER=ar|
0264 : 74 68 75 72 29 29 29 29 |thur))))|

2022-08-04 16:40:44.526 [socket: 3] Receiving packet:
0000 : 00 2D 00 00 02 00 00 00 |.-......|
0008 : 01 3E 0C 01 00 00 00 00 |.>......|
0016 : 01 00 00 00 00 2D C1 00 |.....-..|
0024 : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0032 : 00 00 20 00 00 00 FF FF |........|
0040 : 00 00 00 00 01          |.....   |

2022-08-04 16:40:44.526 [socket: 3] Sending packet:
0000 : 00 00 00 0B 0C 00 00 00 |........|
0008 : 01 00 02                |...     |

2022-08-04 16:40:44.526 [socket: 3] Sending packet:
0000 : 00 00 00 8F 06 00 00 00 |........|
0008 : 00 00 DE AD BE EF 00 85 |........|
0016 : 0B 20 02 00 00 04 00 00 |........|
0024 : 04 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 |........|
0032 : 04 00 05 0B 20 02 00 00 |........|
0040 : 08 00 01 00 00 10 1C 66 |.......f|
0048 : EC 28 EA 00 12 00 01 DE |.(......|
0056 : AD BE EF 00 03 00 00 00 |........|
0064 : 04 00 04 00 01 00 02 00 |........|
0072 : 03 00 01 00 03 00 00 00 |........|
0080 : 00 00 04 00 05 0B 20 02 |........|
0088 : 00 00 02 00 03 E0 E1 00 |........|
0096 : 02 00 06 FC FF 00 02 00 |........|
0104 : 02 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 |........|
0112 : 05 0B 20 02 00 00 01 00 |........|
0120 : 01 00 00 03 00 02 00 00 |........|
0128 : 00 00 00 04 00 05 0B 20 |........|
0136 : 02 00 00 01 00 01 00    |....... |
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include versions of oracledb, Python and the platforms you are using. The full traceback would also be useful. If you set the environment variable `PYO_DEBUG_PACKETS` to any value before running your script do you get any packet output?

Comment: Database version would be useful, too.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga Is it better now?

Comment: Can you add the python-oracledb version to the question (and use the latest version - currently 1.0.3).  Have you got ports mapped correctly in the VM ?  Can you also update the question with what kind of VM you are using and how it is set up?

Comment: Can you try adding the parmeter `disable_oob=True` to the `connect()` call and repeat the attempt?

Comment: And yes, that is much more helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by Anthony Tuininga, disabling the oob (Out of band break) with:
`disable_oob= True` solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we were using Oracle Database native network encryption (not TLS), but we were seeing this same error.
After a lot of searching, we finally found that this is a known limitation of the python oracledb package when running in "thin mode".

From https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_b.html#native-network-encryption-and-checksumming

> The python-oracledb Thin mode does not support connections using Oracle Database native network encryption or checksumming. You can enable TLS instead of using native network encryption. If native network encryption or checksumming are required, then use python-oracledb in the Thick mode. See Enabling python-oracledb Thick mode.

> For example, if you use python-oracledb Thin mode and try to connect to the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) Oracle Base Database where by default native network encryption is set to REQUIRED in the sqlnet.ora file of the OCI Oracle Base Database server, the connection will fail with the error:

> DPY-6000: cannot connect to database. Listener refused connection.
> (Similar to ORA-12660)

Interestingly, they must have updated the error message (DPY-6000 to DPY-4011) in oracledb version 1.3.0 but failed to update the docs accordingly.

Comment: Or maybe the cloud DB now returns a different error? ! Either way, we'll update the docs.

Comment: @ChristopherJones FYI when I downgrade to oracledb 1.2.2 then I see DPY-6000 instead of DPY-4011, which is why I claimed that its a change in version 1.3.0.  Thanks for jumping on it!

Comment: Good to know.  I've already proposed a doc change.  Thanks for sharing the cause - this will definitely help other people.